# ClearInterval: The function body was executed after the expected time but i can't seem to get it off the screen afterwards

Tags: javascript

The clearInterval() method is not working after execution of the function body. here's the code snippet:

```
const clearAll = () =>{
   const del = setTimeout(() => Display.textContent = 'deleted',100);
  clearTimeout(del)
}
clearBtn.addEventListener("click", clearAll)
```

Comment: https://jsbin.com/tevipanexi/1/edit?html,js,output — I can't reproduce the problem

Comment: Please read [ask]. Provide a [mcve] that actually demonstrates the problem. Use the live demo feature of the question editor to do so.

Comment: Your question need more context. Your code snippet works as it should.  What are you expecting from this code? And also refer to the @Quentin comment on how to ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you delete the timeout **before** it happens at least once. Try calling `clearTimeout` after it executes.

```
const clearAll = () => {
   const del = setTimeout(() => {
      Display.textContent = 'deleted';
      clearTimeout(del);
   }, 100);
};
clearBtn.addEventListener("click", clearAll);
```